# Jquery show div based on php variable value of checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I want the div to show on the page if the php variable is equal to 1. I get the $offers from the database and right now it is 1 and the checkbox is checked but there is no div

I tried many different ways including the input check with :checked but nothing works

any help is appreciated!

```
<input type="checkbox" id="offers" value="1" <?php if($offers === "1"){echo 'checked';} ?>> Allow
        <script>
            var offer = <?php echo $offers; ?>;
            if(offer === "1"){
                $(".hide_offers").show();
            }else{
                $('.hide_offers').hide();
            }
            $('#offers').click(function(){  
                $('.hide_offers').fadeToggle();
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<div style="display:<?= ($offer === 1) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: You are getting your input checkbox checked ?

try:
<div style="display:<?= ($offer === "1") ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"></div>

Comment: got it to work. it supposed to be offers not offer that's why haha. thank you!

Comment: lol i locally checked that,with variable named "offer" :P , so lol of me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the checked state and try

```
$('.hide_offers').toggle($('#offers').is(':checked'));

$('#offers').change(function () {
    $('.hide_offers').fadeToggle();
})
```